# Link workbooks in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

My code:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("calculos.xlsm!_" & A149);14;6)
```

Shows "REF!", unless the linked workbook is open.
Can I get the value to show, even when the linked workbook is closed?

Thank you all!

Comment: It is well known that you can't use `INDIRECT` for this. You are reduced to creating individual links. Or if you are comfortable with VBA, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837103/reference-data-in-closed-excel-sheet

Answer (score 0):

Not with `INDIRECT` - as far as I know, it doesn't allow you to access a closed workbook. You have to reference the cell directly if you want to do that.

Comment: Can you help me do that? It's pulling the data, by finding the correspondent cell name.

Comment: I'd be happy to. What's in A149?

Comment: Thanks! A149 cell is "6148". in the other workbook there is a cell named "_6148"

Comment: Probably best to grab a load of sequential cells from your other workbook (maybe in a different worksheet), then reference those ones. It's hard to know really without knowing the significance of your names.